# Sequential power circuit for 18 servos

Tags: fpga, servo, robot

I'm trying to design a servo control board to be a daughter card for DE0-NANO, but run into a problem where all the servos (18 for hexapod) get to the end position on power up.
The initial idea was to implement 'power on reset' circuit, but i was told it a bad idea.

Im looking for some suggestion as to how i can achieve a sequential start up for each leg of the robot. I was thinking maybe some digitally controlled relays or a separate little micro-controller or maybe somebody has a better idea?????

Comment: In hardware format you have 19 states, including a state upon which all servos are OFF. You can use plain logic gates but you would need 5 IC's to do the job. One MPU with 19 to 20 'spare' I/O pins would simplify things a lot. Surf the web for 24 to 40 pin MPU's such as Microchip, Atmel, etc. Look for those in a 5 volt 'DIP' package.

Comment: Do you mean something like this:
http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/1PC-original-DIP-40-MPU-Microcontroller-Atmel-AT89S51-24PU-89S51-40-pin-/110956792468?_trksid=p2141725.m3641.l6368

Im not even sure how to program this thing :/

Comment: That part seems ok. You will have to download the technical and programming data from Atmel, and learn how to program in assembler. It is the easiest language to learn for programming. You will have to do some work on your part before we can help you more.

Comment: I checked it out and i have programmed a similar sort of thing, but i don't think i have the money for additional hardware to go with this.
I was thinking i could do it with 2 IC's that have 2 input AND gates, where one input is held high and is coming from the power lead and the other will come from the fpga as logic of '1' to act as a switch, but they wont handle the current i don't think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem, should have posted it a while ago...

Anyway, fount some omnifets, which are a pair per IC works well in tests, havent actually put the whole circuit together. Also placing a capacitor between the power terminals solved the debounce issue.

Here is a link to the mosfets:
 http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/intelligent-power-switches/8773144/